# kth moment of an arbitrary function

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, moment-generating-functions

I am given that $X\sim N(0,1)$ and that $Y=e^X$, and I am also given that the kth moment of Y is
$E[Y^k]=E[e^{kx}]=M_X(k)=e^{\frac{k^2}{2}}$. This solution suggests that these relationships are self-evident but for the life of me, I can't understand why any of them are true.

Based on my understanding, I would have thought of the kth moment as $\frac{\partial^k}{\partial t^k}$ of $E[e^{tx}]$, that is $\frac{\partial^k}{\partial t^k} \big(e^{tx}\cdot e^x\big)$ but this doesn't seem to make any sense either. I guess I'm struggling with the very concept of the kth moment...

Comment: For some reason $X$ becomes $x$...first ask yourself what is $E[e^{kX}]$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, self evident: I explain.

If $X\sim N(\mu;\sigma^2)$

$\mathbb{E}[Y^t]=\mathbb{E}[e^{Xt}]=e^{t\mu+\frac {t^2\sigma^2}{2}}$

This result has been obtained using the definition of Moment Generating  Function of the Gaussian distribution.

I your Gaussian is standard, the result is

$$\mu_t(Y)=e^{\frac {t^2}{2}}$$

Note also that $Y=e^X$ follows a lognormal distribution

EDIT: this edit is to answer to the latest comment of the O.P.

> First step

Although it can be calculate without difficulty, you can trust that the MGF of a Standard Gaussian is the following function

$M_X(t)=e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$

This function, as per definition, is the following expected value

$\mathbb{E}[e^{Xt}]$

[No difference if we say $M_X(k)=e^{\frac{k^2}{2}}$]

> Second step

Just observe that

$e^{Xt}=[e^{X}]^t$

thus, setting the new rv $Y=e^X$ it is **self-evident** that

$\mathbb{E}[e^{Xt}]=\mathbb{E}[Y^t]$

In other words: the moments of the Log Normal are given by the MGF of the gaussian

EXAMPLE

$\mathbb{E}[Y]=e^{\frac{1}{2}}$

$\mathbb{V}[Y]=e^2-[e^{\frac{1}{2}}]^2=e(e-1)$

You can double check these result [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)

Comment: Thank you. However, some aspects that still confuse me me. I'm having difficulty moving past the definition $M_X(t)=E[e^{tx}]=\int e^{tx}\cdot f(x)dx $. That said, I do see how $Y=E^X$ with an emphasis on it being a big vs little x indicating that it is a random variable.  I do see how  MGF of normal with $\mu=0, \sigma^2=1$ is equal to $e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$, but wouldn't that me the MGF of X, not Y? I guess I'm  confused about how the MGF of one random variables is calculated with the MGF of another "inside" it. Also, I'm assuming t=k here? Is there an $e^{tx}\cdot$"something" that I'm missing?

Comment: @PortMadeleineCrumpet : I made some edits; I hope now the issue is clear

Comment: This was very helpful. My apologies but one more question. This is the only part that remains confusing for me. If it X that $\sim N(0,1)$ then wouldn't it be the case that the k-th moment of Y, that is $M_y(k)$, would be $e^{e^{\frac{k^2}{2}}}$ rather than $e^{\frac{k^2}{2}}$?